# C# Convert indexed pixel to new file bit32

Tags: c#

Does anybody have a sample code on how i could open a tif file, copy it out to a new locate from indexed pixel to new bitmap 32?

I found this http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2008/02/c-indexed-pixel-problem.html  But i'm to new to piece it together.  Is there a possible way to just read this all in memory without actually creating a new file?

What I mean is this.  I have to find the original file (which i already got).  Copy the file to a temp location (which I got).  What I don't understand is how when I copy that new file I need to keep the original size and give the new file a bitmap of 32.

I can't draw an image over the picturebox because C# doesnt really support indexed pixels.

Comment: Please rephrase this: "copy it out to a new locate from indexed pixel to new bitmap 32?"

Comment: Check edit maybe that will help

Comment: i think that if you explain what pixel indexing means you might get more traction. i've done a ton of.Net drawing and am not familiar with that concept.

Comment: Okay, not sure what makes no sense.  How do I convert a .tif from indexed pixel format to PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb

Comment: I'mg oing to close this, it makes no sense to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want I think...

If you dont need to save it, just work with 'bm' after you do the DrawImage, that is your image as a Bitmap...

```
            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("TifFilePath.tif", true);
            Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height);
            Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(tmp);
            grPhoto.DrawImage(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height), 0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            bm.Save("JPGFilePath.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            grPhoto.Dispose();
```

Comment: Remember to dispose the Graphics object.

Answer (score 3):

```
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(original);
```

This will make your newImage start with the contents of original. The difference will be that you will end up with newImage.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, regardless of original.PixelFormat.

Comment: This is great !!